# What is the best native Latex package for plotting?

Tags: packages

I am fairly new to Stackexchange so please excuse for any stupid questions.

Could you please recommend me the best package for plotting which gives quality output for a book.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would surely recommend pgfplots. `http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net`